# Handling and assigning the date into respective categories

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I have an input file like below and trying to convert the multiple customer records into respective quarters and also record per customer. Once the quarter (like Q2 2019) is derived from the data, now the latest one should goto TimeFrame4 and old ones to 3,2,1 order.

So far was able to derive the quarters using the transformer, but after that I was stuck in how to identify and assign them to respective buckets (TimeFrame1   TimeFrame2  TimeFrame3  TimeFrame4). Any ideas on how to implement this effectively (input has 50M records) in DataStage (11.3 Parallel job).

Input:

```
CustID  Contacted_Time
1       2018-12-25
1       2019-06-15
1       2019-01-03
2       2019-02-24
2       2019-03-05
```

I need desired Output like below:

```
CustID TimeFrame1   TimeFrame2  TimeFrame3  TimeFrame4
1       null        Q4 2018     Q1 2019     Q2 2019
2       null        null        null        Q1 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the data by CustId and Contacted_Time desc, filter the data (because I assume there could be more than 4) to four contacts  and once you got the quarters assign a helper column with the number (also in transformer).

Finally a Pivot stage can do the verticalization or you could do this in a transformer as well i.e. with a loop.